# What does this snippet of CMake script of google/protobuf mean?

Tags: cmake

I saw the following snippets in the CMakeLists of [google/protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/3.4.x/cmake/CMakeLists.txt):

```
if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  set(protobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_DEFAULT ON)
else (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  set(protobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_DEFAULT OFF)
endif (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
option(protobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build Shared Libraries" ${protobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_DEFAULT})
```

I'm quite confused. It seems that the **else** branch is meaningless. I'm quite new to CMake, so is there any reasons to write like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier versions of CMake you were forced to write

```
if(<cond>)
else(<cond>)
endif(<cond>)
```

but later versions of CMake are accepting the following syntax too.

```
if(<cond>)
else()
endif()
```

In your case the variable `protobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_DEFAULT` is set either to `ON` if the condition is true otherwise to `OFF`. The `protobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_DEFAULT` variable is then used to set the value of the option `protobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Plus, what does "include(CMakeDependentOption)" mean? I cannot find any module or files of this name in the directory. Is it some native things in cmake?